# How to post an image file to an ASP.NET MVC application using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I want to post an image from an MVC application **A** to another MVC application **B**, so that **B** can save it to disk.

After same research I found out that using an HttpClient would be the right choice.

So in **A** I'm doing a post request:

```
HttpPostedFileBase imageFile;
MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
imageFile.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
byte[] data = target.ToArray();

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);

var response = await client.PostAsync("http://serviceB/Image/Save", byteContent);
```

And in **B** the operation looks like

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public string Save(ByteArrayContent imageFile)
{
   ...
}
```

The problem is that the Save operation of **B** gets never called. But if I change the paramter to something else, e.g. a string, than the operation gets called. So it has something to do with the type of the parameter.

Or maybe I'm totally on the wrong track?

Comment: Try using HttpPostedFile on the receiving end instead of ByteArrayContent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried ByteArrayContent, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: I think you either misread my comment or mistyped yours :)

Comment: Sorry! I used HttpPostedFile but with no success.